# Make CanActivate wait for Subject to compute

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement an authentication guard in my Angular + Firebase application.

I am using a combination of Firebase Authentication (FA) and Firebase Cloud Firestore (FCF) to save users. Therefore, just FA User isn't enough, I need to find the same user in FCF to consider the user logged-in.

During registration, I am saving the users in FCF under the `id` same as the `uid` of that user in FA.

In my `authentication.service`:

```
    export class AuthenticationService {

      public authenticatedUserSubject: Subject<null | User> = new Subject <null | User>();

      public constructor(
        private readonly angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private readonly angularFirestore: AngularFirestore
      ) {    
        this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(    
          (userInfo: null | UserInfo) => {    
            if (userInfo === null) {    
              this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(null);    
            } else {    
              this.angularFirestore.collection<User>('users').doc<User>(userInfo.uid).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
                (user: undefined | User): void => {   
                  if (typeof user === 'undefined') {
                    this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(null);
                  } else {
                    this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(user);
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        ); 
      }   
    }
```

According to my understanding, when the service is initialised, this piece of code will start listening to changes in FA user, following which I will check the FCF user and update `authenticatedUserSubject`.

In my `authenticated.guard`:

```
    public canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.authenticationService.authenticatedUserSubject.pipe(take(1)).pipe(  
          map( 
            (user: null | User): boolean => {
              if (user === null) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/sign-in');
                return false;
              } else {
                return true;
              }
            }
          )
        );
      }
```

Problems:

- The guard does not receive any value from the subject
- If I use BehaviourSubject instead of Subject with an initial value of `null`, refreshing the page will emit `null` as the default value, throwing the user to `/sign-in`

Goals:

- On refresh / load of application, the authenticatedUserSubject should be calculated before the route guard runs
- On logout, the guard should be aware of the state change

Also, if there is a better way to implement this, please let me know!

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz for what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BehaviourSubject` instead of `Subject`. The subject does not emit the last emitted value to the subscriber. Subscriber of Subject will get value only when Subject.next() after the subscription. This is not the case with `BehaviourSubject`. Subscriber will always get the last emitted value on subscription. With this let's try to improve your code a bit and see if your problem solves:

Change your service like this-

```
export class AuthenticationService {

    public authenticatedUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

    public constructor(
      private readonly angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      private readonly angularFirestore: AngularFirestore
    ) {


        combineLatest(this.angularFireAuth.authState, 
                      this.angularFirestore.collection<User>('users').doc<User>(userInfo.uid).valueChanges()
                     )
                    .pipe(
                        tap(([userFromFireAuth, userFromFirestore]) => {
                            if (!userFromFireAuth) {
                                this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(null); 
                            } else {
                                if (typeof userFromFireAuth === 'undefined') {
                                    this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(null);
                                } else {
                                    this.authenticatedUserSubject.next(userFromFireAuth);
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    ).subscribe();       
    }   
  }
```

Having this will avoid chaining of `subscribe()`

Now let's rewrite canActivate like this:

```
public canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

        return this.authenticationService.authenticatedUserSubject
                   .pipe(
                       //this will wait until user becomes NOT NULL
                       skipWhile(user => !user),
                       tap(user => {
                            if (!user) {
                                //this will be useful when user logged out and trying to reach a page which requires authentication
                                //NOTICE - When page is NOT refreshed
                                this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);
                            }
                        }),
                        take(1),
                        map(() => true)
                   );                   
      }
```

Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use BehaviorSubject with initial value of null as you said but all you have to do in your guard is to use `takeWhile` in the following way.

```
public canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.authenticationService.authenticatedUserSubject.pipe(
    tap((user: User) => {
       if(!user){
          this.router.navigate(['/sign-up']);
       }
    }),
    takeWhile((data) => data === null, true)
    );

  }
```

As you know method requires boolean so you can map it before `takeWhile` in pipe.

Hope this works for you cause I had the same problem and it worked.